# IndexOutOfRangeException - Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, custom-font

I write a small script for automatic introduce a rect params in a unity custom font file but i met this error:

IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
FontCustomEditor.setRects () (at Assets/Editor/FontCustomEditor.cs:56)

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;

[CustomEditor(typeof(Font))]
public class FontCustomEditor : Editor {
    public int countX = 10;
    public int countY = 10;
    public string[] horOrient = new string[] { "Left to Right", "Right to Left" };
    public int horOrientIndex = 0;
    public string[] verOrient = new string[] { "Down to Up", "Up to Down" };
    public int verOrientIndex = 0;
    public string characters = "ABCDEFJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY";
    public Font font;

    private bool showParams;


    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();
        showParams = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(showParams, "Automatic Set Rect Positions");
        if (showParams) {
            countX = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Count x", countX);
            countY = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Count y", countY);
            horOrientIndex = EditorGUILayout.Popup(horOrientIndex, horOrient);
            verOrientIndex = EditorGUILayout.Popup(verOrientIndex, verOrient);
            characters = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Characters", characters);

            if (GUILayout.Button("Apply", GUILayout.Width(100)))
            {
                setRects();
            }
        }
    }

    public void setRects () {
        font = (Font)target;
        float rectX = 1f / countX, rectY = 1f / countY;
        int i, j, counter;
        CharacterInfo[] chr = new CharacterInfo[characters.Length];

        for (i = 0; i < countX; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < countY; j++)
            {
                counter = (i * countX + j);

                if (counter <= characters.Length) {

                    float uvx, uvy;

                    uvx = Mathf.Abs((j - ((countX - 1) * horOrientIndex)) * rectX);
                    uvy = Mathf.Abs((i - ((countY - 1) * verOrientIndex)) * rectY);

                    chr[counter + 0] = new CharacterInfo(){ //Line 56 chr.Length = 22; counter = 0;
                        index = characters[counter] + 0,
                        uvBottomLeft = new Vector2(uvx, uvy),
                        uvBottomRight = new Vector2(uvx, uvy + rectY),
                        uvTopLeft = new Vector2(uvx + rectX, uvy),
                        uvTopRight = new Vector2(uvx + rectX, uvy + rectY)
                    };
                }
            }
        }

        font.characterInfo = chr;
    }
}
```

Help me please. I can't understand what i do wrong.

Answer (score 2):

When `counter <= characters.Length` in particular when `counter == characters.Length` the `characters[counter]` will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception.

Indexes in `C#` are zero-based.

P.S. What is your intention to do `chr[counter + 0]`?

Comment: I try to find a problem in a counter type )